# Boto3 considerably slower auth when using X account access

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I have a few profiles which are used to generate boto sessions, as you do.
The Python code base is fairly API call heavy (it is what, it is) and i've noticed some considerable execution differences between boto3.session.Session() with root profile and boto3.session.Session() using a profile that has a root profile.

Has anyone ever come across this before? Or suggest an alternative. I've seen the STS boto3 but the codebase is rather tied to its solution. So I have my hands tied there a little.